# Pass input file data to PHP(Laravel) Using Javascript (VueJs)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Quite simply im trying to pass a file from javascript to PHP using javascript, Ive tried the following but its not picking up the file that ive inputted.

**My Html**

```
    <form v-on:submit="submitForm($event)">
        <input type="file" id="image" v-el="fileInput">
        <button class="btn">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
methods: {
        submitForm: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', $('#image').files[0]);

                console.log(formData);

                this.$http.post('getFiles', formData, function (data, status, request) {
                    console.log('success');
                }).error(function (data, status, request) {
                    console.log('error');
                });
            }
        }
```

And lastly
**The Error**

```
TypeError- Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Im not 100% sure whats the problem here but it doesnt seem to be registering when i upload a file, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#image')` is going to return an array.

So, to get it to work you can:

```
$('#image')[0].files[0]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fixes the error! but now how come no data is being passed still when i upload a .PNG file no data is being returned when i console.log it?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius I'm glad I could help! If this has fixed the error please would you mark the answer as accepted. As for your no data is being returned question, there are too many possible answers and it goes outside of the scope of this question, however, I'd be happy to help if you post a new question.

Comment: When i get a bit more time ill put it forwards as a new question then link you to it if thats alright

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Absolutely fine.